# how to reinitialize the database

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

I have downloaded a demo copy of Hybris for evaluation purposes, and it has been more than 30 days since I downloaded it, and recently I tried to restart it, but it would not, and instead gave me the following message:

"This licence is only for demo or develop usage and is valid for 30 days.
After this time you have to reinitialize database to continue your work."

I am/have been running it on a Mac, and the database is MySQL...

What (UNIX) commands do I use to re-initialise the database, so that I can start up the Hybris Server?

Comment: @admdrew  sounds like he's just asking how to do what the instructions are telling him to do

Comment: I don't know what they mean. But if they provide a sql dump, then just wipe out your mysql schema and re-import it.

Comment: `DROP DATABASE whatever_the_database_is_called`?

Comment: Try go to HAC Platform->Initialization and hit "Init Platform" button

Comment: Hello, here is a dump of the key messages indicating the problem during

Comment: And also..
******************************* 
Your demo/develop
license has expired, it is valid only for 30 days. If you're using devlop
licence you need to reinitialize database to continue your work.
*******************************
hybris licence
[licence.advancedsecurity=true;licence.clustering=true;licence.date=2013.03.27;
licence.email=support@hybris.com;licence.endcustomer=hybris
AG;licence.eulaversion=2.0;licence.expiration=;licence.highperformance=true;
licence.id=000001-001;licence.name=hybris Demo Licence;licence.version=5.0;]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using command line in the Terminal application - goto ***YOURPATH*/hybris/bin/platform** and run the ant clean all then ant initialize command then start hybris:

1. Goto your *platform* directory

`cd $YOURPATH/hybris/bin/platform`

2. Set ant's environment by runing "dot" "space" "dot-slash" *setantenv.sh*

`. ./setantenv.sh`

3. Then run *ant clean all* (to clean environment)

`ant clean all`

4. then run *ant initialize* (to re-initialize environment)

`ant initialize`

5. Re-start the hybris server process by running *hybrisserver.sh*

`./hybrisserver.sh`

Comment: After initializing my all table defined inxml file are removed. Is there any method through which I can recover data? I tried update but no effect @Joe

Comment: You can also just change your system date to a day before the license expired. Start the service and login to the Hybris Admin console. Change the system date back to current date (don’t restart the service). 
Do an initialize from the Admin console. 
You WILL lose your data.

Answer (score 1):

Ant initialize would removes tables that exists in Hybris items.xml files? If you want to reset your DB i have a script that i use across various projects ([can be found here, on GitHub](https://github.com/bvanalderweireldt/reset_db/blob/master/reset_db.sh))

```
#!/bin/bash
MUSER="$1"
MPASS="$2"
MDB="$3"

# Detect paths
MYSQL=$(which mysql)
AWK=$(which awk)
GREP=$(which grep)

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
    then
    echo "Usage: $0 {MySQL-User-Name} {MySQL-User-Password} {MySQL-Database-Name}"
    echo "Drops all tables from a MySQL"
    exit 1
fi

TABLES=$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $MDB -e 'show tables' | $AWK '{ print $1}' | $GREP -v '^Tables' )

for t in $TABLES
do
echo "Deleting $t table from $MDB database..."
$MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $MDB -e "drop table $t"
done
```

Comment: It's not true anymore since 5.1. Only redefined tables are dropped and recreated others stay orphaned. I think the best solution would be to directly drop the database.

Comment: On 5.3 Hybris will generate a drop tables script when you run an initialization, this script drops every tables.

Comment: It might be true in practice (never try myself on 5.3). However the documentation state this "Since hybris Commerce Suite version 5.1, during the initialization process the system no longer removes all tables. Now it only removes those tables that are declared in its current items.xml files. Old tables - orphaned data - stay intact" (source : https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Initialization+and+Update+of+the+hybris+Commerce+Suite)

Comment: Yes you are right it doesn't imply delete every tables, it removes tables that exists in its items.xml files.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Ant command ant initialize and error will go away

Comment: Suggestions should be posted as comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize, [ant all] and rebuild hybris as you have did in first time:

Reason : Evaluation copy works only for 30 days and after it will be expired.

When you start your server it will show in console like below image. Pls Check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also use Hybris Administration Console to initialization

Platfrom -> Initialization